# laravel 8 Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, swagger, laravel-8

I have a problem when using swagger with Laravel it generates Segmentation fault (core dumped) after executing

> php artisan l5-swagger:generate

whereas other commands working well as illustrated in the attached screen.
also, the server unexpectedly changed port I don't understand what goes on.

machine: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

[image]

Comment: The segmentation fault might indicate a PHP bug as well. Try upgrading your PHP version to the latest minor 7.4 release (currently 7.4.23) to see if it persists.

Comment: command `php artisan l5-swagger:generate`

Comment: I already have: PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2021 15:13:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologie

Comment: Yes I noticed that. The latest version of PHP 7.4 is 7.4.23 so if you are indeed encountering a PHP bug it might be worth checking if it's been resolved in the latest 7.4 release. Also you can try `php artisan l5-swagger:generate -vvv` to maybe see more output. Maybe also check the logs for anything unusual

Comment: problem still appear